# How does GADTs as in Haskell-like languages compare to indexed families in dependent types?

Tags: algebraic-data-types, gadt

In Haskell, GADTs are only indexed by types, while indexed families in DT are mainly indexed by terms. With the presence of without-K, it is hard to refute cases just by unifying type terms, while in Haskell the situation is essentially different, where the only way to refute cases is by unifying type terms.

Am I thinking about them correctly? Is there any literature about this?

Comment: This is impentrable to me as a non haskeller what do you mean by "without-K"?

Comment: @BruceAdams K is the eliminator for the type `x = x`, for a fixed variable `x`, compared to J, an eliminator of `Σy. x = y`, for a fixed `x`. K is incompatible with univalence, so if you want univalence you'll need to disable K. There is a non-trivial consequence of this: you can't simply unify types, because there can be non-trivial paths between them (while if you're sure a type is an h-set, then you can still unify them). The standard reference to this is Jesper Cockx's paper "Eliminating dependent pattern matching without K"

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up - https://i.etsystatic.com/12253060/r/il/1ce2d4/2767067032/il_1140xN.2767067032_9vel.jpg

Comment: Your comment also reminds me of this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3870088/1569204 :)  (I am trying to learn more type theory but I have a busy life and its slow going)

Comment: That's just a meme, I'm trying to be serious.

Comment: No offence intended. There are many great questions that can benefit from more background. Adding more background helps if you are within the target audience but sometimes it just highlights more gaps in one's knowledge.

Comment: Tangentially related question I asked on CS SE a few years ago: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132664/relationship-between-inductive-families-and-type-returning-functions